# Find folders that has no data in it and get their folder names

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find folders that has no data in it and get thier folder names.
The first and second folders are named randomly in numbers and has data in random folders.
the codes are

```
path = 'M://done/mesh/*'    
FL = glob.glob(path)
FL2 = glob.glob(FL[0] + '/*')  

FL2
['M://done/mesh\\41\\23',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\24',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\33',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\34',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\35',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\36',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\43',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\44',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\45',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\46',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\47',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\53',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\54',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\55',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\63',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\64',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\65',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\66',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\67',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\74',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\75',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\76',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\77',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\85',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\86',
 'M://done/mesh\\41\\87']


FL2[24][24:26] + FL2[24][27:30] + '0000'      # why do I need [24:26}, [27:30]???

finding_files = ['_Caminfo.dat','running.csv']
print(FL2[0] + '/0000/02_output/' + FL2[0][24:26] + FL2[0][27:30] + '0000/' + fn1[0])
'41860000'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.listdir` to find empty folders, like below:

```
import os

folder_list = ["D:\\test_1", "D:\\test_2"]

empty_folders = []

for folder in folder_list:
    try:
        if not os.listdir(folder):
            empty_folders.append(folder)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

print(empty_folders)
```